# How to direct http://localhost/DM/index/fb1ffc41 to http://localhost/DM/fb1ffc41

Tags: .htaccess

How can redirect `localhost/DM/index/fb1ffc41` to `localhost/DM/fb1ffc41` via `.htaccess` file.

`fb1ffc41` this code is for short URL similar like Google short URL service.

Comment: You should be more specific in defining the problem. It "looks like" the short code is limited in the type of characters it contains? Is there a limit in length? Also, the solution can be dependent on any existing directives you might have in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: i had added 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mss_token=$1
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mss_token=$1

code to redirect index.php to index

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^DM/index/([a-f0-9]+)$ /DM/$1 [R,L]
```

This assumes the "short code" is 1 or more hexadecimal digits.

This is a temporary (302) redirect.

Comment: What happens? An error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? By itself that directive redirects `/DM/index/fb1ffc41` to `/DM/fb1ffc41`, as stated in your question. You may have a conflict with existing directives. Please add your current `.htaccess` file to your question and include an outline of your file structure.